# Chef chef-manage not appearing in browser?

Tags: centos, chef-infra

I have installed the Chef server core package and reconfigured ...

[image]

Then I've run the chef-server-ctl install chef-manage --path /root (I've downloaded the packages!!) and reconfigured and I get the browser page saying please install chef-manage ....

[image]

I'm at a loss ... tried to go to the IP address when only installed chef-server but this message too ... so have been around the same loop several times ..

packages are:

[image]

Help gratefully accepted ...
Thanks
EJK

Comment: Glad that you could solve your problem. Please don't post console output as code in the future, but as formatted text instead.

Answer (score 0):

Doh! I'm a numpty ... after the:

```
# chef-server-ctl install chef-manage --path /root
# chef-server-ctl reconfigure
```

The I forgot to do this!!!!

```
# chef-manage-ctl reconfigure
```

All working now ...
Numpty .. helps to follow the right process ;-)
EJK